# RDF valid characters

Tags: xml, rdf

Are all XML valid characters considred valid in RDF?

I have found this on Wikipedia on XML valid characters:

```
    U+0009, U+000A, U+000D: these are the only C0 controls accepted in XML 1.0;
U+0020–U+D7FF, U+E000–U+FFFD: this excludes some (not all) non-characters in the BMP (all surrogates, U+FFFE and U+FFFF are forbidden);
U+10000–U+10FFFF: this includes all code points in supplementary planes, including non-characters.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDF Literals are Unicode however when you write those literals down (encode them) in some syntax, then you have to take care to follow the rules of the syntax.  RDF/XML is an XML syntax (I edited it in 2004) and as such restricts the Unicode characters and has its own encoding rules so you can escape characters such as `'`, `<`' and `>`.

You also have to use a Unicode encoding to turn the characters into sequences of bytes, UTF-8 and UTF-16 are common.  These don't restrict the characters you can write down.

The answer then is really dependent on what you mean.  In practice, it's unlikely you'll want to use a Unicode character that cannot be legally written in XML or RDF/XML since it includes a large range of Unicode.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My problem is that a triple-store(AllegroGraph) encounters an error in the Sax parser when finding characters with the code values: `66373 (hex 10345), 136090 (hex 2139a), 134123 (hex 20beb)`, but they should be accepted. Does this mean that there is a bug with the triple-store?

Comment: Unicode 6 (2011) range is U+0 U+10FFFF (hex) as you say in the question so only the first one is valid.  U+10345 is probably junk too since it comes from the "private use area" which is unlikely to be something portable.  Sounds like a data problem.

Answer (score 0):

One should better refer to the original specifications that just using Wikipedia. The set of [allowed characters in XML 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets) is:

```
Char ::= #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]
/* any Unicode character, excluding the surrogate blocks, FFFE, and FFFF. */
```

The set of allowed characters in XML tag names is even more restricted.

The set of allowed character sequences in RDF literals is [defined as](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-concepts/#section-Graph-Literal) "being a Unicode [UNICODE] string, which SHOULD be in Normal Form C [NFC]". The set of Unicode characters is codepoint U+0000 to U+10FFFF ([minus 66 non-characters](http://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html#nonchar1) depending on your point of view).

Anyway, the set of allowed Unicode characters includes characters explicitly forbidden in XML. See also the SO question [Why are "control" characters illegal in XML 1.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404107/why-are-control-characters-illegal-in-xml). In XML 1.1 the [set of characters was broadened](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#charsets) to

```
Char ::= [#x1-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]
/* any Unicode character, excluding the surrogate blocks, FFFE, and FFFF. */
```

One still cannot express for instance the character (U+0000) in XML although it is allowed in RDF literals.