# XML parsing error (SOAP): Illegal character

Tags: java, xml, soap

here's the issue:

my task is to manage DB sync via SOAP (please, don't ask me why, I've just been told to do it that way), and I get a not constant error while transferring data. It can appear after 500 records passed, can appear after 20000, can even not appear at all, so I suppose that it's not corrupted data in the DB.

Log of this error:

```
[com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 20))
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,48901]]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:141)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:151)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy282.getExportGRP(Unknown Source)
    at by.nces.oais.service.WebService.getExportGRP(WebService.java:365)
    at by.nces.oais.service.WebService.importDataToBase(WebService.java:98)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.InstanceResolverImpl$1.invoke(InstanceResolverImpl.java:143)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:149)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:94)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:961)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:910)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:873)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:775)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:116)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.MonitoringPipe.process(MonitoringPipe.java:142)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:119)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:961)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:910)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:873)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:775)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.processRequest(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:212)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.process(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:144)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:119)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:961)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:910)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:873)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:775)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:386)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:640)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:263)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:163)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.JAXWSServlet.doPost(JAXWSServlet.java:145)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:688)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 20))
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,48901]]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:436)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:372)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.BridgeImpl.unmarshal(BridgeImpl.java:124)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.api.Bridge.unmarshal(Bridge.java:237)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.glassfish.BridgeWrapper.unmarshal(BridgeWrapper.java:261)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.message.stream.StreamMessage.readPayloadAsJAXB(StreamMessage.java:315)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.ResponseBuilder$Body.readResponse(ResponseBuilder.java:496)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.ResponseBuilder$Composite.readResponse(ResponseBuilder.java:199)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.readResponse(StubHandler.java:252)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:177)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:256)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:128)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 20))
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,48901]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwInvalidSpace(StreamScanner.java:666)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.readTextPrimary(BasicStreamReader.java:4542)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2859)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1065)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.XMLStreamReaderFilter.next(XMLStreamReaderFilter.java:96)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(StAXStreamConnector.java:196)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:370)
    ... 72 more
|#]
```

I've used URLEncode/URLDecode and forced UTF-8 for the transmitted data, like it was suggested in similar SO question with this Illegal character issue - it didn't help.

Also there is another error, which happens very rarely:

```
[com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Unexpected close tag </tip>; expected </tipi>.
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,16133]]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:141)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:151)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy283.getExportGRP(Unknown Source)
    at by.nces.oais.service.WebService.getExportGRP(WebService.java:365)
    at by.nces.oais.service.WebService.importDataToBase(WebService.java:98)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.InstanceResolverImpl$1.invoke(InstanceResolverImpl.java:143)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:149)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:94)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:961)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:910)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:873)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:775)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:116)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.MonitoringPipe.process(MonitoringPipe.java:142)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:119)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:961)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:910)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:873)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:775)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.processRequest(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:212)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.process(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:144)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:119)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:961)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:910)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:873)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:775)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:386)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:640)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:263)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:163)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.JAXWSServlet.doPost(JAXWSServlet.java:145)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:688)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Unexpected close tag </tip>; expected </tipi>.
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,16133]]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:436)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:372)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.BridgeImpl.unmarshal(BridgeImpl.java:124)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.api.Bridge.unmarshal(Bridge.java:237)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.glassfish.BridgeWrapper.unmarshal(BridgeWrapper.java:261)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.message.stream.StreamMessage.readPayloadAsJAXB(StreamMessage.java:315)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.ResponseBuilder$Body.readResponse(ResponseBuilder.java:496)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.ResponseBuilder$Composite.readResponse(ResponseBuilder.java:199)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.readResponse(StubHandler.java:252)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:177)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:256)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:128)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Unexpected close tag </tip>; expected </tipi>.
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,16133]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.constructWfcException(StreamScanner.java:606)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:479)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:464)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.reportWrongEndElem(BasicStreamReader.java:3263)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.readEndElem(BasicStreamReader.java:3190)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2809)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1065)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.XMLStreamReaderFilter.next(XMLStreamReaderFilter.java:96)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(StAXStreamConnector.java:196)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:370)
    ... 72 more
|#]

[#|2014-10-23T16:36:13.302+0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=8837;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|StandardWrapperValve[WebService]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet WebService threw exception
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:487)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.OutputWriter.flushChannel(OutputWriter.java:108)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.OutputWriter.flushChannel(OutputWriter.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.flushChannel(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:426)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:498)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.flush(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:476)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.action(ProcessorTask.java:1287)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.Response.action(Response.java:268)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:380)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:175)
    at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer.flush(UTF8Writer.java:103)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.flush(BufferingXmlWriter.java:225)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.flush(BaseStreamWriter.java:261)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.XMLStreamWriterFilter.flush(XMLStreamWriterFilter.java:71)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamWriterUtil.getOutputStream(XMLStreamWriterUtil.java:103)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.message.jaxb.JAXBMessage.writePayloadTo(JAXBMessage.java:382)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.message.AbstractMessageImpl.writeTo(AbstractMessageImpl.java:149)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.message.FilterMessageImpl.writeTo(FilterMessageImpl.java:168)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.encode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:127)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.encode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:285)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.encodePacket(HttpAdapter.java:421)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.access$100(HttpAdapter.java:99)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:650)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:263)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:163)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.JAXWSServlet.doPost(JAXWSServlet.java:145)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:688)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
|#]
```

I'm stuck with this for 1 week almost, maybe you've got any thoughts.
Appreciate your help.

Comment: Not every character you can store in a database will be legal in XML. You have [a control character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/404107) in your data.

Comment: The point is that this error appears from time to time on the same pieces of data in different places. It can even not appear at all on that particular piece. If it would happen on the exact same record every time, then I would agree with you that it's data problem.

Comment: Another moment: all the data from DB is being encoded, so the error appears not on decoding operation but on deserializing data from received xml.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CDATASection`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/CDATASection.html

to enclose text that you believe may contain XML control characters.  When you pull from the database, simiply enclose any fields of concern in `<![CDATA[*text*]]>` and you should be fine!

Alternatively, you can manually escape any control characters in the string by replacing them as follows:

```
& = &amp;
< = &lt;
> = &gt;
" = &quot;
' = &apos;
```

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/09/how-to-replace-escape-xml-special-characters-java-string.html#ixzz3TLceVqKi

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what is the main reason of this error but i can say, in second error you closed the tag with `</tip>` but expected to close with `</tipi>`

Look at your `<tipi> </tip>` and change with `<tipi> </tipi>`

Comment: I've got no control over this xml. It's being constructed in the background automatically. The tag should be named "tipi", but it seems that it just somehow cuts the last letter while generating this tag and gets </tip> instead of </tipi>