# Community Data Access CDA &#26 character invalid

Tags: pentaho, cda

I have created a number of queries in CDA for use with Pentaho Report Designer.  I can link to my CDA queries on the server but when I try to preview some of the queries I get the following error:

Character reference "&#26" is an invalid XML character.

The queries run without a problem on the CDA previewer.

Thanks in advance,
Fergus

Answer (score 1):

`&#26` is indeed an invalid XML character in XML version 1.0. In this case, more specifically, we're talking about the character &. The quick explanation as to why [*control characters*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404107/why-are-control-characters-illegal-in-xml-1-0) are illegal:

> [...] a markup language should not have any need to support
>   transmission and flow control characters and including them would
>   create a problem for any editors and parsers in binary conversion.

Pentaho Report Designer parser won't handle these control characters. Therefore, my suggestion is to change these values in your XML to `&amp;` which is one of the five [predefined entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML) in the XML specification, responsible to render the character &.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I would try what you say but the problem has mysteriously vanished.  I opened Report Designer today and everything worked as it should.  I know I restarted the report designer the last day and it made no difference.  Perhaps restarting the PC is what did it.